# thenFinally() hides the assertion error in webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, error-handling, selenium-webdriver

I have test case where it

1. browses to url
2. signs in
3. asserts something
4. signs out

If assertion fails, the test doesn't execute signout.

So I decided to use `thenFinally()`, but the problem with it is it hides the assertion error. I see my test passing instead of failing.

Can someone please help what I am doing wrong or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd want to use `then()` instead of `thenFinally()`, and pass a callback function that signs out, and another callback function that asserts the error.

```
async().then( 
  function(success) {
    signout();
  }, 
  function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```